using subtotal in an arrayformula with if
From someone elses question, who was trying to sum the maximum value in each row of two columns, I found this:
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(B3:B>N3:N,B3:B,N3:N)))
which works!
but i need to apply that same process to a subtotal, so i can make use of its ability to only sum rows that are not hidden. unfortunately i cannot get this to work, it errors on only accepting a range as input:
=arrayformula(subtotal(109,IF(B3:B>N3:N,B3:B,N3:N)))
tried to apply array formula and the if logic to subtotal, getting an error


You may try:
=sum(map(B3:B,N3:N,lambda(Σ,Λ,if(subtotal(103,Σ),max(Σ,Λ),))))

